# Create directories with incrementing variables as part of directory name using Bash within for loop

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a bash script which allows me to automate the creation of multiple directories with incrementing names.

For example, I am trying to create the directories named v0v1, v1v2, ... , v40v41.

I have tried using a 'for' loop, where I create a variable and set this to be equal to the current value of i+1 (where 'i' is the current loop iteration), but it is not working as expected.
I have managed to get the variable to increment (and have checked this using 'echo'), but I cannot get it to become part of the new directory name.

The code I have written is as follows:

```
for i in {0..40}; do let r=$((i+1)); mkdir v$iv$r; done
```

However, the directories produced have names only containing the first variable value (i.e. v0, v1, ..., v40), and do not include the 'v$r' at all.

Does anyone have any ideas how to use two variables at once in the same filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in {0..40}; do let r=$((i+1)); mkdir v${i}v$r; done
```

When bash sees the expression `v$iv$r`, it substitutes in for variables `iv` and `r`.  But, of course, there is no `iv`.  So bash substitutes in the empty string.  The solution is to use braces to assure that bash knows where the variable name ends.  Thus: `v${i}v$r`.

Comment: For something this simple I'd skip the separate `r` and just  `for i in {0..40}; do mkdir v${i}v$((i+1)); done`

Answer (score 1):

```
printf 'r=%d ; mkdir v$((r-1))v${r} ;' $(seq 2 41) |sh
```

You don't need a shell loop at all.